# ajax being called 4 times on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax

First of all, I am addicted to jQuery but I want to create something that's framework free and as light-weight as possible so I'm ajaxing myself.

I have this code :

```
    function ajax(url)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
   else
        console.log( "error");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

which I call once in my head using :

```
ajax("url");
```

However, I see 3 "error" logs in my console and the 4th is the rsponseText.

Anyone knows why does that happen and how do I avoid it? I have **no** other script in my page.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. You see 3 'error' logs because onreadystatechange fires 3 times before your request completes... If you want them to stop remove: else{ console.log( "error");}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes
onreadystatechange call for every state.... more infos on http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

try this

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  if(xmlhttp.status==200) {
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
  } 
  else {
     console.log('error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
```

This callback is used for more than readystate 4 and 200. Try adding xmlhttp.status to your error message as such

```
function ajax(url)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
   else
        console.log( "error - readyState: "+xmlhttp.readyState);
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

`ajax(url)` is not called more than once, but `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a bug and also it is not an error what you see is onready statechange event and always log in the else block. There are not just success and fail state in the httpObject.

Please check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms534361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As you can see there are 4 states and only the `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` means actual success, request complete and also no server error.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the readyState will move from 1 to 4 int (in ie, lesser in other browsers).

Try:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
   else if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        console.log( "error");
}
```